# How to Run PowerShell v3 console in v2 mode

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

In recent updates of Windows Server 2008 R2, they are pushing Windows PowerShell V3.0 also along with that.
But, our scripts are built and tested in V2 till now.
How can I run PowerShell V3 Console in V2 mode.?

Note: I tried "-Version 2" while starting the PowerShell.exe. But it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In what way is `powershell.exe -version 2` not working?  This is how you run v2 when v3 is installed.

BTW, make sure that the PowerShell 2.0 engine is installed.  Check Windows Features:

[image: Windows Features - PowerShell 2.0]

Comment: I checked Windows Features and there is not Windows PowerShell 2.0 engine installed in that.
There is no possible option to install it from that window as well.

Comment: when I try powershell.exe -version 2 and open PowerShell, then also on Get-Host command it is giving version as 3.0

Comment: The option to install PowerShell 2.0 must be unique to Windows 8 then.  No matter, if you're on a down level OS and have installed WMF 3.0, running `Powershell.exe -version 2` is how to start 2.0.  The copyright should say 2009 and $PSVersionTable should indicate the PSVersion is 2.0.  How exactly are you starting powershell?  From PowerShell or Windows Run or a scheduled task...?

Comment: How can I check the installed version and other details of WMF?

Comment: Go to Programs and Features, click View Installed Updates and search for KB2506143.

Comment: I have the same issue. I run Powershell -version 2
Then run $psversiontable. Still PSVersion = 3 ... Any workarounds? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling kb2506146 for win2k8 R2 sp1

Comment: Run powershell, then within powershell run `powershell.exe -version 2`, then run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` to check the version's changed.

Comment: I'm in Windows 10, using Powershell 5.0. In the Windows features I can see the activated "Powershell 2.0", but when I run the powershell -version 2.0 it says the .NET framework v2.0 isn't installed. Firstly, this could help someone else, secondly, I wonder what to do now - whether it's safe and needed to install the old 2.0 .NET version!? Anyone?

Comment: Go back into Windows Features and enable `.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)`.  That should get you going.