# Run PowerShell script at end of bundle chain execution

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I am creating a exe installer using Wix Bootstrapper.

In the bundle chain I am installing some exe files.

In the end I want to execute a PowerShell script to do some additional tasks. How is it possible

Here is the bundle chain and I have mentioned where I want to execute a PowerShell script.

```
   <Bundle Name="sample" Version="0.0.0.0" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="fsfsddssdsdsd">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
        <Chain>

            <ExePackage
                SourceFile="something.exe"
                InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
                PerMachine="yes" >
            </ExePackage>

            <ExePackage
                SourceFile="anything.exe"
                InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
                PerMachine="yes" >
            </ExePackage>


            **EXECUTE POWERSHELL SCRIPT HERE**
            
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options for now:

1. Create msi that is doing all your stuff.

You can run powershell script as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045955/run-powershell-script-from-wix-installer)

2. Create your own bootstrapper application that will run script after all exe was installed. As I remember there's special event for this case.

Here you can find [great article about it (C#)](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/). Also you can easily find how to do it using C++.

Comment: A MSI is not an option

Comment: Can you please elaborate on option 2?

Comment: I posted [link](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/) with step by step guide how to implement it. Just follow it) I can help if you'll have some questions during implementation. But as for me, msi looks easier to implement.