# Running a PowerShell script before Install with WixV4

Tags: installation, package, wix, windows-installer, wix4

I'm trying to do a custom action with a Wix installer script but documentation with v4 is kinda terrible and I can't find a working example anywhere. All the code that worked with V3 doesn't work with v4 and I can't find how to do it anywhere, could somebody please provide a working example? I want to run a custom powershell script to execute itself before the installing procedure begins.

Tried generating a log file but it doesnt help whatsoever
https://github.com/damienbod/WiXPowerShellExample/blob/master/SetupWithPowerShellScripts/Product.wxs -- doesn't work

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/f18d7e628361cd3f2ff14dd3326cbeea68df004f/src/wix/WixToolset.Core/BindFileWithPath.cs nowhere is it explained how to use this plugin

eve finding the binarykey that has been changed to binaryref has been a challenge...

[Run PowerShell script from WiX installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045955/run-powershell-script-from-wix-installer) also does not work as the syntax has changed a lot

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
     xmlns:powershell="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/powershell">

    
    
    <?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
    <?define ProductCode = "{0F7564E3-56A2-447C-BDA1-8A0D38A0DD5E}"?>
    <?else?>
    <?define ProductCode = "{B304F287-8D2A-4233-8F47-D2D3FD8B07C7}"?>
    <?endif?>
    
    <?define UpgradeCode = "{1E6CD331-2C24-468D-AB2A-6CC0A40B8909}"?>

    <?define BuildVersion = 1.2.3.4?>   
    
  <Package Name="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform))"
           Manufacturer="!(loc.Company)"
           Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">


            <SetProperty Id="Dzonson"
            Before ="Dzonson"
            Sequence="execute"
            Value="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -Version 3.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command &quot;&amp; '[#djole.ps1]' ; exit $$($Error.Count)&quot;" />

        <CustomAction Id="Dzonson" BinaryRef="Wix4UtilCA_$(sys.BUILDARCHSHORT)" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="Dzonson" Before="InstallFiles"></Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>


      

    

       
      
      
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

      <Icon Id="Icon.ico" SourceFile="$(var.ConsoleApp1.ProjectDir)\app.ico"/>
      <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon.ico"></Property>
      <Property Id="APPURLINFOABOUT" Value="https://e-smartsys.com/"></Property>

      <ui:WixUI
          Id="WixUI_InstallDir1"
          InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
          />
      <WixVariable
       Id="WixUILicenseRtf"
       Value="bpl.rtf"
        />
      <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)/Assets/Background.bmp"/>
      


              <Feature Id="Main">
        
        
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Package>
```

Comment: Can you update your question and share what code you have so far? Rather than having us do your homework for you, let us help point out the parts you don't understand so you can learn how it works.

Comment: Hey @RobMensching thank you for the reply and the mighty fine tool. Yeah, I want  to learn how all of it works but I'm really not sure where to start since I learn best from examples :). I have edited the post above to contain the code that I have so far. The installer just does a rollback and doesn't launch my ps script.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Don't use WixShellExec to run PowerShell. Just use a standard Exe CustomAction. ShellEx is used to launch targets via explorer.exe, like open an HTML file (in the default browser). It's for very specific cases.
2. You scheduled your action Before InstallFiles but you are referencing the installed location of your script with `[#djole.ps1]`. Your PowerShell execution is probably failing because the file isn't there yet.

If you want to learn by example check out my weekly show [Deployment Dojo](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDlzbQXIs18slmqmdlS10_de_Cps-QRg6).