# What causes "powershell -version 2" to fail?

Tags: powershell, version

I have been running PowerShell v3 for some time on several different systems. On occasion I wish to check compatibility or other issues with v2 so I switch to v2 within an existing PowerShell with this:

```
PS> powershell -version 2
```

As a matter of course I then use either `$hosts.Version` or `$PSVersionTable` to do a sanity check. But on one machine when I did this they both reported I was still in a V3 shell. I tried again from scratch; same result. I also tried invoking it from a DOS shell instead of a PowerShell; again, same result. Then to check my own sanity(!) I went to another system, did the same sequence, and it worked as expected--I did indeed switch from a V3 to a V2 environment.

The only other observation I have is that on the system that worked, I got a 2009 copyright notice when it started up the inner shell; on the system that did not it showed 2012.

Final detail: of the two machines mentioned, it worked on Win8 and failed on Win7 enterprise but I really doubt that is a relevant factor here.

I would be really surprised if (a) this is a PS bug or (b) I am the only one seeing the issue, yet web searching has been fruitless for me thusfar. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Intriguing problem: Going back to basics, I start my PowerShell from a shortcut, I append –version 2 thus: "WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe" -version 2.
This led me to speculate that your rogue machine had a second copy of PowerShell installed.  I am using Windows 7 and I get the 2009 copyright message.

Comment: I had another idea, would an uninstall --> re-install solve the problem?

Comment: @Guy:Interesting thought... "which powershell" revealed the expected `C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` but just for grins I typed that path explicitly with a `-version 2` tacked on... same unexplained result.

Answer (score 1):

One reason would be that .NET 2.0 is not installed on the failing system, I cant recall if it had to be already installed prior to v3 or you can install it after upgrading to v3.

Comment: I had not thought of that, Shay, but upon checking I have 2.0 installed already.

Answer (score 1):

Quick search turned up this, just an idea?  Maybe V2 is not installed?

[Is Version 2 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864429/how-to-run-powershell-v3-console-in-v2-mode)

Comment: Some good tidbits in the post you referenced but, alas, I did not find the smoking gun there.