# PowerGUI script editor does not recognize the updated powershell version?

Tags: powershell, powergui

I have ARS Shell 1.7.0 installed as part of ARS 6.9 & my MS (windows) powershell version is 4 (obtained by $PSVersionTable.PSVersion, screenshot below)

[image] [image]

however when I do the same within the PowerGUI I get version as 2? This has started after i upgraded by shell version to 1.7 from 1.6.9 (PowerGUI worked fine with 1.6.9). I have no clue why is this happening & due to this I'm unable to use any quest cmdlets within the PowerGUI editor which make debugging my scripts an impossible task!

Screenshot from PowerGUI :

[image]

I get below error when i try to load ActiveRolesManagementShell from PowerGUI:

[image]

UPDATE: tried running Powershell (x86) but still the result is same, can anyone please let me know where in the world is PowerGUI picking up version 2 ?

[image]

Comment: I know that you run powershell with a downlevel engine version. Is it possible that PowerGUI has a switch or setting somewhere that is doing that? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864429/how-to-run-powershell-v3-console-in-v2-mode

Comment: Thx for getting back, unfortunately there is no switch for PowerGUI :(

Comment: Is it possible that you have version 2.0 installed of the 32-bit PowerShell but version 4.0 installed of the 64-bit PowerShell and that explains the difference? Try running the (x86) version of PowerShell and doing $PSVersionTable there to see.

Comment: Negative, tried running Powershell(x86) but still it shows version 4, screenshot update din the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the PowerGUI Script editor to version to **3.8** & it resolved the issue. PowerGUI now recognizes v4

People using ver 3.2 should make a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be due to a change in ARS 1.7.0 that is forcing the PS2 engine to be required, per this:

> Windows PowerShell 4.0 and Windows PowerShell 3.0 are designed to be
>   backwards compatible with Windows PowerShell 2.0. Cmdlets, providers,
>   snap-ins, modules, and scripts written for Windows PowerShell 2.0 run
>   unchanged in Windows PowerShell 4.0 and Windows PowerShell 3.0.
>   **However, due to a change in the runtime activation policy in Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 4, Windows PowerShell host programs that were written
>   for Windows PowerShell 2.0 and compiled with Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR) 2.0 cannot run without modification in Windows PowerShell 3.0 or
>   Windows PowerShell 4.0, which are compiled with CLR 4.0. The Windows
>   PowerShell 2.0 Engine is intended to be used only when an existing
>   script or host program cannot run because it is incompatible with
>   Windows PowerShell 4.0, Windows PowerShell 3.0, or Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4.** Such cases are expected to be rare.
>
> Many programs that require the Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine start it
>   automatically. These instructions are included for the rare situations
>   in which you need to start the engine manually.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/starting-the-windows-powershell-2.0-engine