# How to uninstall PowerShell 5.1 and revert to older version on Windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7-x64

Needing to test an upgrade to PowerShell 5.1 and hoping to revert to an older version on this machine. Tried uninstalling Windows Management Framework 5.1: KB3191566 with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Run PowerShell v3 console in v2 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864429/how-to-run-powershell-v3-console-in-v2-mode)

Comment: @iRon I'm not so sure, based on the "test an upgrade to PowerShell 5.1." There are several steps/installs needed to get up to PS v5.1 on Win7 and it is possible they're trying to work on the upgrade process itself.

Comment: @BoogaRoo: We are trying to test a package for the upgrade process. Thanks for clarifying